# Change Color of Single Letter in Label String?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, colors, label

I have a project in WPF 4 and VB.net. I need to change the color a single letter in a word in a label (the label's content changes quite a bit). I really am not sure if this is possible, but if it is, I'd appreciate help on figuring out how. TY!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Label is a content control so any type of content is permitted inside a label.You can easily do your requirement by something like

```xml
<Label>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="T"/>
        <TextBlock Text="ext"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Label>
```

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar and I'm wondering if this technique will work and be bindable. For example highlighting all the uppercase letters in a dynamic string such as 'ThisIsMyTextBlock'. Would this be achievable using this approach?

Answer (score 15):

A cleaner way would be using the flow-content-capabilites of a TextBlock:

```xml
<Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="L" Foreground="Green"/>
        <Run Text="orem Ipsum"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

This limits binding a bit though, if that is needed.

Comment: This is a better solution if your text needs to wrap

Comment: FYI, the spaces/line-breaks between the `Run` tags introduce spaces in the text being displayed.

Answer (score 10):

The cleanest method i found so far is using a [`TextEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.texteffect.aspx):

```xml
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="Search">
        <TextBlock.TextEffects>
            <TextEffect PositionStart="0" PositionCount="1" Foreground="Red"/>
        </TextBlock.TextEffects>
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

This colors the "S" red. You can of course bind any of the involved properties if they need to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented something like this in our project, this will be static though - I'm not sure if that's what you need. You can change the content of the label as often as you need, but it will always have a red * at the end. I added a style to the project like this

```
<Style x:Key="RequiredFieldLabel"
       TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
          <TextBlock Text="*"
                   Foreground="red" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can use this style on a label anywhere in your project.

```
<Label Content="Enter Name:"
       Style="{StaticResource RequiredFieldLabel}" />
```